# Issue while creating a node using firefox instance in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have created a hub using Selenium Grid using the following command :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role hub
```

Now, I am trying to create a node for firefox instance using the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node  
-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/console -browser browsername=firefox -port 5555
```

Once I execute it, I get the following as shown int he screenshot:

[image]

Here I am getting `v:null`
Why is this coming out to be null ? Can anyone help me on this please?

I am new to Selenium Grid and any help will be highly appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given above has typo, whis will end up with creating node with default capabilities, instead of specified ones.

If you want to create node with single firefox instance available, do this:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/console -browser browserName=firefox -port 5555

Please note I used browserName instead of browsername - this is case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the `-browser` from the args and add `-` before `browsername`
like this

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/console -browsername=firefox -port 5555
```